# Evitar reinicio de acumulador al ejecutar de nuevo el programa

Tags: java

Necesito que al iniciar un ciclo `for` el valor del acumulador no se reinicie cada vez que ejecuto el programa.

En este caso cada vez que inicia el ciclo `for` el valor del acumulador es 0 y necesito que cada vez que inicie el programa su valor sea igual al que acumula dentro del `for`.

```
int acomulador = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++)
{    
   acomulador = acomulador + i;    
}
```

Comment: para eso existen las bases de datos, o puedes guardar el valor de acumulador en un json o un archivo txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guarda la variable en un archivo y cárgala cada vez que ejecutes el programa. Un ejemplo podría ser:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("acumulador.txt");
        int acumulador = 0;

        // Lee el archivo
        try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);) {
            acumulador = reader.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // Muestra el valor actual del acumulador antes de iterar
        System.out.println("Valor Actual: " + acumulador);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            acumulador = acumulador + i;
        }

        // Guarda el valor en un archivo
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);) {
            writer.write(Integer.toString(acumulador));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

En este programa la variable se guarda en un archivo de texto en la misma ruta donde está el ejecutable. Si no existe el archivo, el acumulador toma el valor de 0 y crea el archivo al final del ciclo.